# Cannot source url inline using process substitution

Tags: bash, shell

This isn't working:

```
. <( curl --silent -L  \
 "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/shell/master/test.sh")
```

but this is:

```
. <( curl --silent -L  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/shell/master/test.sh")
```

and I suspect it has to do with the multiline `\`  in the first example. But there is not error with curl, anyone know what's going on? Any way to do multiline command using `\` inside a subshell?

Comment: What error are you getting?  I just replaced `.` with `cat` to view the file, and both options worked.

Answer (score 2):

> But there is not error with curl, anyone know what's going on?

It's because you're using the `--silent` option, which (as described in the fine manual) prevents any error from being shown. Either remove it or also use the `--show-error` option.

> Any way to do multiline command using `\` inside a subshell?

Yes. Just make sure there's no space / tab or other frog character (like a carriage return or NUL byte) between it and the newline.